# Set camera Depth Texture to None via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, urp

I'm instantiating a camera in my code:

```
GameObject go = new GameObject("Second Camera");
Camera cam = go.AddComponent<Camera>();
```

My question is: how to set **Depth Texture** as None in the code?

[image]

When I instantiate, it always starts with this *Use Pipeline Settings* option and I cannot change it no matter what I do. I tried `cam.depthTextureMode = DepthTextureMode.None` but nothing changes. How can I set this to None?

My main camera needs to draw the depth texture, so I don't think disabling the depth texture in the URP settings is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That property is coming from `UniversalAdditionalCameraData` class.

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;

var data = go.GetComponent<UniversalAdditionalCameraData>();
data.requiresDepthOption = CameraOverrideOption.Off;
```

Setting `requiresDepthTexture` also works

```
data.requiresDepthTexture = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot! Although I had problems accessing the `UniversalAdditionalCameraData` 
using `GetComponent`. For some reason it seemed to be null all the time. My solution was accessing it via the camera component itself, instead of doing the `GetComponent` in the camera's GameObject: `cam.GetUniversalAdditionalCameraData().requiresDepthOption = CameraOverrideOption.Off;`. Worked just as well.

Comment: Yeah the component is automatically added to the camera in editor, because your camera is created with script,  the method is necessary to add `UniversalAdditionalCameraData` in runtime.